# How to prevent QTextEdit only scroll horizontally when text is entered at the end of the screen?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a QTextEdit which requires a horizontal scroll bar. I only want to scroll the screen automatically when the user is at the very edge of the screen. This is the setup for the QTextEdit:

```py
self.editor = QTextEdit()
self.editor.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
self.editor.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.NoWrap)
self.editor.setTabStopDistance(QFontMetricsF(self.editor.font()).horizontalAdvance(' ') * 16)
self.editor.setFont(self.font)
```

I expect that the TextEdit only scrolls when I am at the very end of the screen, for example at the end of a long line that goes off screen.

I also expect to not scroll unless the user is at the end of the screen. This happens, however, even when I enter text into a line that ends even before the midpoint of the screen. I want to prevent this behaviour.

I want user scrolling to work fine, I only want the TextEdit to not scroll automatically unless the text is off the edge of the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. Are you saying that you see the text scrolling even while typing *away* from the right edge? Are you typing standard text or is it LTR (Left To Right)? Also, can you provide a [mre] and some text examples we could test with? If you could also make a video of what happens, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

I've tracked the issue down to a line where I moved the text cursor around programmatically. This meant that the text edit would need to scroll. The solution was as simple as getting the horizontal scroll position before the movement and resetting it after.

Comment: Sorry but this is exactly why we need a [mre], as right now not your question nor this answer would ever be useful to anybody, since it's unclear how the problem was initially created in the first place and how you actually solved it.